# Как можно сверстать такую сложную кнопку?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

Как можно сверстать такую сложную кнопку?

[image: Кнопка]

Comment: Обрезать чёрный фон в любом графическом редакторе, сохранить картинку и сделать ссылку на неё `<img src="картинка-кнопки.png">`

Comment: автор, не ясно для чего ставишь тег SVG если ответы ждешь css ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что кнопка не должна быть статичной, поэтому добавил анимацию блика, которую можно отключить при необходимости (*комментарии в коде*). Вариант на чистом CSS:

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #000; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh; }

.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 276px;
  width: 729px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: bold 100px "Comic Sans MS";
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #252525, #868690) 1 100%;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  background: #868690;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 13px #0e0e0e;
}
.btn>span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scaley(1.27) translate(7px, -7px);
  border: none;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  text-shadow: 6px 1px 5px black;
}

.btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 13px solid #8f8f8f;
  border-left: none;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #434449, #000106);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}
.btn::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 150%;
  width: 200%;
  background: linear-gradient( 55deg, transparent 46%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, transparent 54%);
  filter: blur(5px);
  /* Для анимации блика */
  margin-left: -170%;
  /* Для статичного блика
  margin-left: -18%; */
}

/* Для анимации блика */
.btn:hover::after { animation: blink 1.1s ease-in-out forwards; }
@keyframes blink { to { margin-left: 170%; } }
```

```html
<div class="btn"><span>BARPHOTO</span></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Для векторной графики это не проблема … просто открыть Corel Draw и нарисовать а после этого все стили вынести в отдельный файл...например в style.css, этот пример я проверил в Microsoft Edge и в IE11

Автору очевидно надо было с hover эффектом … не ясна суть вопроса была … **отредактировал**

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}

.item {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -130px;
  left: -80px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff 40%, #fafafa, #fff 40%);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: 0.48s cubic-bezier(0, 0.39, .72, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 -4px 20px #fff;
}

.item:hover:after {
  top: -150px;
  left: 450px;
}

#fill {
  fill: url(#linearGradient1);
}

#left_border {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

#right_border {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

#txt {
  fill: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 60">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="linearGradient1">
      <stop offset="45%" stop-color='#666' stop-opacity='50%' />
      <stop offset="55%" stop-color='#000'stop-opacity='50%'/>        
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" id="fill" />
      <path d="M100,0 0,0 0,60 100,60" id="left_border" />
      <path d="M100,0 200,0 200,60 100,60" id="right_border" />
      <text x="50" y="40" id="txt">bigtext</text>
    </a>
  </svg>
</div>
```